# Unable to read my external hard drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs, external-hdd

whenever i plug in my external hard drive it show a error as follows :

```
#Unable To Mount 125 GB File system#

Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 13: ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Record 6 has no FILE magic (0x0)
Failed to open inode FILE_Bitmap: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb8': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

what does this mean??? Please help.....Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If it's a NTFS partition, you should follow the message advice, boot into a machine with windows then plug the drive. Check the which is the letter assigned to the drive and run the command line, press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> then type `cmd` and hit enter.

You will get the command prompt, write:

```
chkdsk /f LETTER:
```

LETTER being the letter assigned to your drive. Wait a long time (depends of the size of the drive) reboot windows twice with the drive plugged, then try to access from Ubuntu.